# Is it possible to prevent anyone from stripping debug symbols (e.g., labels) from an ELF binary?

Tags: linux, gcc, binary, x86, elf

> Is it possible to prevent anyone from stripping debug symbols (e.g., labels) from an ELF binary?

Does any protectection mechanism exists that makes it possible to prevent an attacker to strip debugging symbols from an executable?

In this case, the debugging symbols could provide useful information about the binary that the owner would not loose.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think, debugging symbols provide more information to attacker and make the binary vulnerable. It's not a very good idea to deploy binaries with debug information.

Comment: What sort of "attacker" do you have in mind here?

Answer (score 2):

> Does any protection mechanism exists that makes it possible to prevent an attacker to strip debugging symbols from an executable?

Debug symbols are by definition not necessary for the execution, and can be stripped or overwritten.

You *could* sign or checksum the entire executable (including the debug symbols), store that signature on disk and verify it at runtime, thus preventing *any* modification of the binary.

> In this case, the debugging symbols could provide useful information about the binary that the owner would not loose.

You appear to have it backwards: debug symbols help an attacker much more than they help the owner.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at what is in an elf file?  This would be trivial to do (remove the symbol table).  So yes it is possible

Symbol tables are for debugging purposes, so what if you can run a program not in a debugger...